# how to create a contact form emailer in rails 4 when the web page is on the client side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up a rails 4 contact form emailer but the entire app and form is living in a public directory and is static html and javascript.

What would be the best solution to set up a rails email sender. I know I would have to set up the form to use the rails format erb template but I want to have the web site be a single page app.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your application has a weird design...

If you still want to do this, you have to make your form point to a custom action which will send the mail.

in order to do that run first

```
rails g controller contact deliver
```

to generate the controller, then change the route in config/routes.rb

```
get 'contact/deliver'
```

to

```
post 'contact/deliver'
```

Next generate the mailer

```
rails g mailer contact_mailer contact
```

you can now create the action in app/controllers/contact_controller.rb to send the mail :

```
protect_from_forgery except: :deliver
def deliver
  ContactMailer.contact(params.permit(:email, :subject, :message))
  redirect_to :back
end
```

and define your mailer in app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb

```
def contact(message)
  @email = message[:email]
  @subject = message[:subject]
  @message = message[:message]

  mail to: "me@me.org"
end
```

You can finally pass your instance variables to the view in app/views/contact_mailer/contact.text.erb

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks for the help. indeed this sounds like a solution however i was thinking I would use ajax instead to make a post to the rails backend which will invoke the mailer. What do you think about this method?

Comment: you can use jquery_ujs and add "data-remote='true'" to your form tag